# How to render a chart using highstocks in highcharts in angular 6?

Tags: typescript, charts, highcharts, angular6

I want to implement highstock using highcharts in angular 6.

I have rendered it successfully using div tag and id as container as in the example of hoghcharts-official forum.But I don't want to it like that.

I want to render it using

```
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [constructorType]="chartConstructor"[options]="chartOptions">
</highcharts-chart>
```

Here highcharts is -> `import * as HighCharts from 'highcharts'`, constructorType is -> 'stockChart' and chartOptions -> I have given chartoptions same as in the link given

[here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-stock?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

I tried it But I am getting errors as follows :

```
ERROR Error: Highcharts error #17: www.highcharts.com/errors/17
    at Object.a.error (highcharts.js:10)
    at a.Chart.initSeries (highcharts.js:250)
    at highcharts.js:275
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at a.each (highcharts.js:29)
    at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:275)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> (highcharts.js:250)
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:31)
    at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:249)
    at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:249)
```

and then infinite loop goes on for the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of null
    at B.titleCollision (stock.js:127)
    at B.render (stock.js:124)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> (stock.js:130)
    at a.Chart.a.<computed> [as render] (highcharts.js:20)
    at a.Chart.firstRender (highcharts.js:275)
    at a.Chart.<anonymous> (highcharts.js:250)
    at a.fireEvent (highcharts.js:31)
    at a.Chart.init (highcharts.js:249)
    at a.Chart.getArgs (highcharts.js:249)
    at new a.Chart (highcharts.js:248)
```

Can anyone please help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might not work because you named your import `HighCharts` and passed `Highcharts` to the highcharts-chart component. To fix the problem update your import name.

`import * as HighCharts`

```js
<highcharts-chart [Highcharts]="Highcharts" [constructorType]="chartConstructor"[options]="chartOptions">
</highcharts-chart>
```

Additionally, check if you imported and initialized all required modules, the error that occurred usually means that the user is trying to use the series/functionality that requires additional module. Example:

```js
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_exporting from 'highcharts/modules/exporting';
HC_exporting(Highcharts);
```

**Docs references:** 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-angular#to-load-a-module



Keep in mind that the example you attached was built with `angular-highcharts` - 3rd party wrapper that is not officially supported.

Here you can find a Highcharts Stock demo built in the `highcharts-angular` (the official wrapper): https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-stock

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Mateusz Kornecki. I am using Highcharts only everywhere It's the typing Mistake here. But the stackblitz-demo helped me to resolve my issue. Thanks a lot :)